# How to get graphical view of jitter, packet loss etc of an RTP pcap using tshark?

Tags: voip, rtp, pcap, tshark, jitter

I know that wireshark GUI tool has a feature (RTP analyse), that will analyse the RTP stream and give all the details of the stream, like loss, jitter and even play the audio if possible.

I want to get the same info using command line. Right now im using tshark. How do it get the graphical view (even CSV file will do) using tshark ? or any other command line tool ?

Im able to get aggregated info of the pcap using

```
tshark -nr pcapanalyseloss.pcap -qz rtp,streams
```

output

```
========================= RTP Streams ========================
    Src IP addr  Port    Dest IP addr  Port       SSRC          Payload  Pkts         Lost   Max Delta(ms)  Max Jitter(ms) Mean Jitter(ms) Problems?
   13.56.125.48 27334     10.126.2.44 18054 0xED92B8F2 ITU-T G.711 PCMU  3493     2 (0.1%)         3506.73    382789845.71           15.92 X
    10.126.2.44 18054    13.56.125.48 27334 0xED97B1E2 ITU-T G.711 PCMU  2844     5 (0.2%)         4102.53          260.40           11.57 X
==============================================================
```

im looking for a detailed view, like this https://packetpushers.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/ws7-1.png

Thank you

Comment: I do not believe that there is a way to output a jitter png with the CLI. This is better suited for [the Wireshark Forums](https://ask.wireshark.org) or [our networking sister site](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/) than Stack Overflow as its focus is not code. Please note that it's against SO policy to ask for recommendations (this is the exact kind of post that reddit.com/r/networking encourages; however).

Comment: Thank you...Will post it in the forums you mentioned